# How to apply box-shadow only on 3 sides?

Tags: css, box-shadow

I use my CSS page below. He applies a box-shadow on the 4 sides.

I want it to be applied only to the right, bottom and left.

How to apply box-shadow only on 3 sides ?

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
```

Comment: I use this tool to find how I like it. It will come down to self preference. https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do something like:

```css
.shadow-box {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 10px gray, 
    -10px 8px 15px gray, 10px 8px 15px gray;
 }
```

```html
<div class="shadow-box">Box with shadows</div>
```

Comment: Please explain how the above code provides a working solution.

Comment: For people looking for more explanation, this site has great examples and playgrounds. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

Answer (score 0):

box-shadow supports only X & Y offset, but you can achieve box-shadow to 3 directions, by providing appropriate value to the offsets.

**Tip :** *In chrome via inspect element you can easily get the exact values and preview that before using it.*

Please refer to snippet below.

```css
#boxShadow {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #cdcdcd;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px #3fab83;
}
```

```html
<br><div id="boxShadow">
</div>
```