# css filter on three sides of element

Tags: html, css, css-filters

in the example below I need a `drop-shadow` on all sides except on the top
I tried this - without success

```
filter:drop-shadow(-3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
```

```css
.story{
width:50vw;
margin:0 auto;
height:50vh;
background:orange;
border-radius:0 0 14px 14px;
filter:drop-shadow(-3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
}
```

```html
<div class='story'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a `clip-path` that will clip only the top part then you can use a basic box-shadow (or a drop-shadow)

```css
.story {
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50vh;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 0 0 14px 14px;
  box-shadow:0px 3px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  clip-path:polygon(-50px 0,calc(100% + 50px) 0,calc(100% + 50px) calc(100% + 50px),-50px calc(100% + 50px))
}
```

```html
<div class='story'></div>
```

To undestand what the clip-path is doing:

```css
.story {
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50vh;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 0 0 14px 14px;
  box-shadow:0px 0 0 100vmax red;
  clip-path:polygon(-50px 0,calc(100% + 50px) 0,calc(100% + 50px) calc(100% + 50px),-50px calc(100% + 50px))
}
```

```html
<div class='story'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a built-in way in css to do this. I copied the div and put it right on top of the first one and added the shadow to the right. Hth...

```css
.story {
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50vh;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 0 0 14px 14px;
  filter: drop-shadow(-3px 3px 3px black);
}

.story2 {
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50vh;
  background: orange;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 3px 3px black);
}
```

```html
<div class='story'>
  <div class='story2'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51731766/1171702).

Comment: drop shadow is visually better than a box shadow, that's why I want the first one. You solution is technically ok, but I hope there is a more native way

Comment: S**t, was that in the original Q? it didn't register.